# Python, Selenium Webdriver: The element is not visible for Firefox.

Tags: python, selenium, popup, webdriver

I'm trying to iteract with a webelement on a page that has edit link that opens a popup. In opened popup I have simple input field and Apply/Cancel buttons. In my script I do the following to enter some text to the input field:

```
def enter_text(self, text, action):
        if self.is_element_present(self._input_locator):
            self.selenium.find_element(*self._input_locator).send_keys(text)
        if action == 'Apply':
            self.selenium.find_element(*self._apply_button_locator).click()
        elif action == 'Cancel':
            self.selenium.find_element(*self._cancel_button_locator).click()
```

When I run my script in Chrome - everything works fine, all webelements are found and input text is entered to the field. But when I run exact same script in Firefox - it opens popup window (which means it became visible for Webdriver) with input field and 2 buttons but the text is not getting entered to the field which causes error:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with'
```

Why can this happen if the popup is actually opened (and I can see it) but Webdriver tells that it is not visible? Also, I put several sleeps just to get sure that popup loaded and then the text is entered but it did not help.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the definitions of the web elements? Do they have inner spans? Try clicking on the inner span if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

1: make sure your HTML is valid, eg by running it thru the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/).  broken html is a common cause of different behaviours in different browsers.

2: have you definitely switched selenium over to the popup, using, eg:

```
for handle in self.selenium.window_handles:
    # identify popup window's handle somehow
    self.selenium.switch_to_window(handle)
```

As an aside, if you haven't come across `selenium.implicitly_wait(3)`, it's dead useful as a way of avoiding `time.sleep`s and wait-for constructs..

Answer (score 0):

Witch Firefox version and Webdriver version are you using?

Please try the following:

- Update Webdriver to the last version
- If you are using firefox 17-18, downgrade it to lower version (I guess FF12 will work)

Please try that and tell me what happens,

Regards